# Orchid root rot

Tags: roots, orchids, rot, protection

[image]

[image]

[image]

Hi! I would like to ask for some insights on having roots with black/brown spots and roots with a green tip, but the membrane has turned from white to brown.

Is this a sign of root rot on my quarter terete vanda orchid? If it is, what are some possible remedies to this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

vanda  orchids are from Thailand and love a tropical environment

the metal you have the plant in is a possible reason why.
(the roots don't like the metal as it is toxic for them as they will absorb it! )

the roots should not have black or brown spots as that means the plant is suffering from some sort of toxicity

try using clay or plastic pots as that would not affect the roots and prevent the roots from touching the metallic container.